# Displaying an array with unknown values into a lable box

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am new to coding with visual basic.

Recently, I was tasked by my professor to write a programme that allows the user to enter five words. The words then should be sorted and displayed in alphabetical order.

To do this I decided the best approach would be to use an array.

My thinking was that if I created a counter at the start, I can create a different value for each column of the array when a button is clicked.

If the array exceeds five I have a message box pop-up that resets the code (although I realise I will also have to clear the contents of the array).

My problem arises in displaying the array. I have looked for solutions online, and none have helped me as of yet.

I need to sort the array into alphabetical order and then display it in a label box (lbl_DisplayArray). As I do not know the values of the array, this has proved tricky.

My code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Dim Array(4) As String
                Array(i) = txt_UserWords.Text
        End Sub

        Private Sub btn_Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Next.Click
                i += 1
                If i >= 5 Then
                        i = 0
                        MsgBox("Array Limit Exceeded. Code Reset")
                        txt_UserWords.Text = ""
                End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub btn_Sort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Sort.Click
                lbl_DisplayArray.Text =


        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Look at string.Join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using

```
private myList as new List(of String).
```

Then to sort them you just call the .Sort() method. Just call `.Add(txt_userWords.Text)` to add the new string and use .Count to see how many of them you have.

When you're adding them to the label you can use

```
lbl_DisplayArray.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, myList)
```

You'll need the list of to be a member of the class instead of a local variable (as you have declared Array). This will keep it alive and allow you to access it in other methods.

---------- edit ----------

```
Public Class Form1

    private myList as new List(of String)

    Private Sub btn_Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Next.Click
            If myList.Count >= 5 Then
                myList.Clear
            Else
                myList.add(txt_UserWords.Text)
            End If
            txt_UserWords.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Sort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Sort.Click
            myList.Sort()
            lbl_DisplayArray.Text = String.Join(vbcrlf, myList)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm very new to visual basic, could you explain where to add these elements into my code?

Comment: The code works perfectly. Thank you very much. If you have the time could you explain why you used the myList function over an array?

Comment: Lists are far easier to use than arrays particularly for simple applications such as this. Memory wise the list will only use as much memory as it needs for its current size vs the array which allocates it all immediately. But for this app it's entirely down to simplicity.